# reading and writing int from/to shared memory in c

Tags: c, pthreads, shared-memory

I'm trying to make a program where a thread writes an integer into a shared memory location and then the other thread reads and prints that integer. the problem I'm facing is that the second thread keeps reading the integer as -1.
here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <string.h>


struct args {
    void* memptr;
    sem_t* semptr;
};

void *p1(void *vargp) 
{
    void* memory = ((struct args*)vargp)->memptr;
    sem_t* semaphore = ((struct args*)vargp)->semptr;
    //sem_wait(semaphore);
    //sleep(0.5);
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
    {
        if (!sem_wait(semaphore)) {
            printf("got in if p1\n");
            sprintf(memory, "%d", i);
            sem_post(semaphore);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    if (!sem_wait(semaphore)) {
        sprintf(memory, "%d", 0);
        sem_post(semaphore);
        sleep(1);
    }
    sleep(0.1);
}

void *p2(void *vargp) 
{
    void* memory = ((struct args*)vargp)->memptr;
    sem_t* semaphore = ((struct args*)vargp)->semptr;
    sleep(0.1);
    while(1)
    {
        if (!sem_wait(semaphore)) {
            printf("got in if p2\n");
            if((int)memory == 0){
                break;
            }
            printf("%d\n", (int)memory);
            sem_post(semaphore);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
} 

const int ByteSize = 4;
const char* SharedName = "memNameTest";
const char* SemaphoreName = "semNameTest";


int main() 
{   
    int fd = shm_open(SharedName, O_RDWR, 0644);
    ftruncate(fd, ByteSize);
    void* memptr = mmap(0, ByteSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    sem_t* semptr = sem_open(SemaphoreName, O_CREAT, 0644, 0);
    sem_post(semptr);
    struct args *Share = (struct args *)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    Share->memptr = memptr;
    Share->semptr = semptr;

    pthread_t thread1, thread2; 
    printf("Before Thread\n"); 
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, p1, (void*)Share);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, p2, (void*)Share);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    printf("After Thread\n");



    munmap(memptr, ByteSize);
    close(fd);
    sem_close(semptr);
    unlink(SharedName);
    return 0;
    exit(0); 
}
```

I have tried changing `(int)memory` into `*((int*)memory)` but that resulted in a segmentation error.

(edit)
as suggested I tried this in a single-threaded program and got it to work as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    /* the size (in bytes) of shared memory object */
    const int SIZE = 4;
    /* name of the shared memory object */
    const char* SharedName = "memoryInt";
    /* create the shared memory object */
    int shm_fd = shm_open(SharedName, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644);
    /* configure the size of the shared memory object */
    ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);
    /* memory map the shared memory object */
    void* memptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0); 

    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
        /* write to the shared memory object */
        //sprintf(memptr, "%d", i);
        memcpy(memptr, &i, sizeof(int));
        printf("%d\n", *((int*)memptr));
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

though this still doesn't work in a multi-threaded program as i get a segmentation fault.
this is the output:

```
Before Thread
got in if p1
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Your handling of pointers seems to indicate that there's some confusion, perhaps you should practice these things with something simpler (single-threaded).

Comment: `p1()` isn't writing an `int` to the buffer, it is writing a null terminated string of characters. `p2()` isn't reading anything from the buffer, it is just converting the address of the buffer to an `int`.

Comment: It is often the case that you start with a problem, then you add another thread and you got two problems :) Get it to work in a single thread: it must work that way before you even worry about threads!

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to show what happen on your terminal when you compile your program.
Secondly, the function sprintf has the declaration:

```
sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

That means the p1 will write the null terminated string of character. In your code, i dont understand why you use the void pointer `memory` instead of using char pointer as the description. You should verify the read/write function by using single-threaded before applying to the multi-thread.